# Project Euler 8 Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var num = 10234657899876543299999991;
var strNum = num.toString();
var total = 1;
var greatest = 1;

for(var start = 0; start <= strNum.length; start ++){
  for(var i = start; i <= start + 3; i ++){
  total *= strNum.charAt(i);
}
  if(total > greatest){
    greatest = total;
  }
  total = 1;  
}

alert(greatest);
```

My code is designed to loop through var num, and return the highest multiple of 4 consecutive numbers. In this example, the answer is clearly 4 x 9 in the block of nines towards the end of var num. However, what is happening is that once the multiple starts getting less (i.e after the first block of 2 nines and 2 eights), the results are no longer stored, and the result of 8 x 9 x 9 x 8 is the one that is returned. How can I tell my code to continue looking for large multiples all the way through var num?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting `num` to a string, store it as a string already:

```
var strNum = "10234657899876543299999991";
```

This will give you the expected result, which is 9^4 (or 6561):

```js
var strNum = "10234657899876543299999991";
var total = 1;
var greatest = 1;

for(var start = 0; start <= strNum.length; start ++){
  for(var i = start; i <= start + 3; i ++){
  total *= strNum.charAt(i);
}
  if(total > greatest){
    greatest = total;
  }
  total = 1;  
}

alert(greatest);
```

The problem is that, in your code, `strNum` is not exactly a string with all digits of `num`. Instead, it's a string of its scientific notation. Check this:

```js
var num = 10234657899876543299999991;
var strNum = num.toString();
console.log(strNum);
```

And that (1.0234657899876543e+25) is way over the [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER):

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toExponential())
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I'm pleased it was such a simple fix.